# Obtener valores desde un DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Como puedo obtener el valor de un DropDownList en el controlador,se supone que hay un DropDownList el cual al seleccionar una opción y pulsar buscar debería filtrar y arrojar los datos en la tabla que hay abajo en esa misma vista, estoy trabajando de la siguiente manera.
Es la manera correcta o estoy equivocado?

Vista:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controlador:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás en lo correcto, desde el DropDownList puedes obtener el valor y después de eso puedes hacer el filtro al precionar un botón, o puedes agregarle al control DropDownList el atributo AutoPostBack="true" y agregarle el evento [OnSelectedIndexChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Tienes dos formas de hacerlo, los dos devuelven el valor seleccionado.

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue; 
DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
```

[Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx) te dejo la ayuda de MSDN, ahí viene todo lo que tienes que saber sobre el control `DropDownList`

Comment: gracias,logre hacer lo que quería